Are .equals() and == the same thing in Kotlin?
If I try to override both the equals function and the == operator through override operator fun equals, I get an error of "Conflicting overloads".
Does this mean that == and .equals() are the same thing? And if not, why can't I override both?
Code example:
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if(other !is Injury){
        return false
    }

    return bodyRegion == other.bodyRegion && injuryNature == other.injuryNature && injuryName == other.injuryName
}

override operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean{
    if(other !is Injury){
        return false
    }

    return bodyRegion == other.bodyRegion && injuryNature == other.injuryNature && injuryName == other.injuryName
}

In the above example, I get:

Conflicting overloads: public open fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean defined in com.redacted.redacted.Injury, public open fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean defined in com.redacted.redacted.Injury


What do you mean by “override both”? Can you give a concrete code example?

For the most part, == is an alias for calling equals. More accurately, according to this documentation, a == b is equivalent to a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null). Overriding Any::equals(Any?) is how you overload the == operator for a given type. So, as previously asked, what do you mean by "try to override both", and can you provide a [mre]?

@Slaw sure, I added the code.

Ah, I see. You don't need to (and as seen, cannot) define two equals methods like this. Pick one and delete the other, as they are the same function anyway. When overriding an operator function, you don't need to include the operator keyword in the override's signature (it's implicitly there regardless).


Does this mean that == and .equals() are the same thing?

They are not 100% the same, but they are both overridden by a single override of equals(). So if you try to do both override operator fun and override fun, it will indeed be an error. Just override the regular equals() method, and it will change the behavior of == too.
As others mentioned, using a == b is equivalent (in behavior) to a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null). There are also a couple subtleties regarding type checking (== is slightly more strict on operand types than a pure equals() call), but that is irrelevant for the way you override equality.

"Just override the regular equals() method" - the documentation and the source code define it as expect/actual open operator fun equals, so I usually follow the same signature with override operator fun. I thought the non-operator version was just a carry-over from Java, isn't that the case?

That's a fair assumption. All I can say is that I believe in this case it's not how it works (at least AFAIK)

Where is == "more strict"? In Java it checks for reference equality, but in Kotlin it clearly checks for value equality when the .equals function is overridden in the class.

@k314159 The Any::equals method is, as you said, already an operator function given it includes the operator modifier in its signature. You don't need to explicitly include the operator modifier in the override's signature because the fact it's an operator function is inherited. You see the same thing with the open, internal, protected, and possibly other modifiers. Though apparently not suspend (perhaps forcing verbosity was deemed to be more beneficial in this case). I'm not sure where any of this behavior is documented, however.

@Aashishkebab Using a == b is "more strict" than a.equals(b) in the sense that the compiler verifies if testing a equals b "makes sense" given their static types. See Why is "".equals(1) Valid but "" == 1 Invalid in Kotlin?.

This. Sorry for being vague in the parentheses :) I edited to make it clearer
